# Python Selenium can't find any element on a webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate a simple task with selenium. Login to this website: https://www.lernsax.de/. I'am trying to locate the element via xpath but that doesn't work at all and I get a `NoSuchElementException`. I'am using Chromedriver and  I have tried to use different locating methods like

`find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name`

but I always get this error. I have already tried different websites and it works fine with xpath.

**Any help would mean a lot!**

Here's my full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://lernsax.de")
loginbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="skeleton_main"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a')
loginbtn.click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

and the full error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../lernsax.py", line 6, in <module>
    loginbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="skeleton_main"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a')
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\LernsaxAutomation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\LernsaxAutomation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\LernsaxAutomation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\LernsaxAutomation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="skeleton_main"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

Comment: Can you pls share your code and full error?

Comment: Yes, there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **iframe** is present on the page, so you need to first switch the driver to the iframe and the operate on the element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://lernsax.de")
# Switch to iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('main_frame'))
# Find the element by applying explicit wait on it and then click on it
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='skeleton_main']/div[1]/div[2]/div/a"))).click()
```

Comment: Do you mean `WebDriverWait(driver, 20)` ? Not `WebDriverWait(browser, 20)` ?

Comment: @EngineeredJonas yeah i made a mistake there, have corrected it, please pick the updated ans

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the login form is contained within an iframe, which you will need to switch into, and perform the operations you need. Add below before you click on login button.

```
driver.switch_to.frame('main_frame')
```

Answer (score 1):

As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.lernsax.de/wws/9.php#/wws/101505.php?sid=97608267430324706358471707170230S5c89c6aa')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#content-frame")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-qa='reporting-filter-trigger-toggle'][data-ember-action]"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.lernsax.de/wws/9.php#/wws/101505.php?sid=97608267430324706358471707170230S5c89c6aa')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='main_frame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='mo' and text()='Login']"))).click()
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: LernSax]

---

### Reference

You can find a coupple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: Thank you, makes sense!