# I can't get element on PHP website with Selenium

Tags: python, php, selenium

I need to build a script to automate action on [this website](https://openboxmobile.redicom.cloud/login.php) that is builded using PHP.

For that, I'm using the Selenium package for python.

So I instantiate the browser and made login using the xpath to get the elements

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://openboxmobile.redicom.cloud/login.php')
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_utilizador"]')
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_password"]')
username.send_keys(USERNAME)
password.send_keys(PASSWORD, Keys.ENTER)
```

## The problem

After log-in on the page, I need to click on a input type="button", so I'm trying to get the element using xpath again.

```
product_import = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="but_2"]')
```

but the following exception was raised.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="but_2"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.71)
```

### What I already tryed

I tryed to get the element using full x-path and id

I also printed the base64 image after loging to check if the page was updating and it is.

**IMAGE OF PAGE HTML**

[image]

#### Update

I looked at some other questions and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60776454/python-selenium-cant-find-any-element-on-a-webpage), so I tried to run the following code, but a TimeoutException was raised.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="imain"]')))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="but_2"]'))).click()
```

#### Update 2

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
product_import = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="but_2"]')
```

this code crashed on the `product_import` line, so, apparently, the driver switched to the correct iframe, but `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:` was raised

## SOLUTION

I used chromium to get full xpath of two frames that was wrapping my application (I discovered that by getting the full xpath of my button and I see that was too short, that because he was wrapped).

So I ran the following code

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "/html/body/iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "/html/frameset/frameset/frameset[2]/frame[1]")))
import_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input[2]")
import_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

If the button was actually a button and not an input type button he could be click by using this command.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input[2]"))).click()
```

Comment: Please share relevant html code for the same. Since we cannot login we can see by ourself.

Comment: right! I will update, sorry.

Comment: Please see below illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input tag is in iframe, in Selenium you will have to switch to iframe first and then you can interact with the input tag.

Please switch it like this :

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "mainframe")))
product_import = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="but_2"]')
```

You will have to **import** these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

You will also have to make sure that the input is under just this **iframe**. There could be a possibility of nested `iframes` as well.

Also, **iframe id** has to be unique in `HTMLDOM` to make this to work.

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Also, I would say if id is unique please use id not xpath for this :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="but_2"]')
```

A way better approach would be with `WebDriverWait` `element_to_be_clickable`. Something like this  :

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "but_2"))).click()
```

Comment: I'm trying to make work!

Comment: The direct catch on but_2 raised a TimeoutException and the following line raised the same error as before (please see if the "imain" part is correct) => `WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "imain")))`

Comment: There is just one iframe on the HTML

Comment: No you should use `mainframe` not `imain`. The one I have given in my solution.

Comment: Again the TimeoutExeption was raised, I ran the same command as you typed. This page gave other two <iframe> tags, but none of them are wrapping the element, they can be the problem cause?

Comment: I saw your update this this works `iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
product_import = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="but_2"]')`, and `but_2` is throwing no such element then you would need to check in HTML DOM, if it is representing the right element. `Steps to check:` are already mentioned in my solution above.