# Filling out fields using selenium (poor html here)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to accomplish the following things:

- Input my email
- Click submit
- If "check again later" close, rinse and repeat until the other message appears "you are in!"

Here's the code I have so far:

```
PATH = "D:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
email = "yada@yada"

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("-incognito")
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation']);
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=option)

browser.get("https://WEBSITE.com/")


email_field = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
email_field.send_keys(email)

time.sleep(5)
browser.close()
```

The error this prompts when runningis:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="email"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=106.0.5249.119)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know much about html, but I see that the email field is inside of an iframe

```
<div class="form-row">
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email:" data-validate="required,email">

      <div class="required-message">Oops! You forgot your Text here</div>
      <div class="invalid-message">Oops! Invalid email address</div>
```

Where is my approach failing?
All I want is to enter the email field, press enter, and close the browser after 5 seconds.

Edit:

Trying the suggestion below, prompts this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ME/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.1/scratches/ChromeBot.py", line 18, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))
  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Could this be my path? I stored the chrome driver on the D drive

Answer (score 1):

**For the first point, about the error message** - Selenium is saying that it can't find the target element you're looking for - Sometimes this is due to your script executing before the page has fully loaded.

**To your second point about the iframe** - You'll want to switch the driver to the `iframe` first, then use the `sendkeys` function on that `iframe`

You may be able to try something like below:

```
    browser.get("https://WEBSITE.com/")
    
    # Adding the line below to wait until the target element is present, or 10 seconds have passed
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.id, "email")))
    
    # Switch to iframe
    driver.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('your_iframe_id_here'))
    
    # Then get the target element, and send keys
    email_field = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
    email_field.send_keys(email)
```

The thread below may help with waiting until the page has fully loaded to execute your script:

[Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable)

The thread below may help with the iframe a bit more:

[Python Selenium can't find any element on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60776454/python-selenium-cant-find-any-element-on-a-webpage)